# Using a for loop with lambda in filter method?

Tags: python, loops, lambda

```
a = [ ]

for i in range(int(input())):
   a.append(int(input()))

print(max(filter(lambda x: x%i != 0 for i in range(2,x), a)))
```

This is a code aiming to print the greatest prime number among an array of numbers. But shell keeps returning syntax error. What's wrong with this?

Comment: I'd say `lambda x: all(x%i != 0 for i in range(2,int(x**0.5)+1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda expression returns a generator expression. You want it to test if the condition is `True` for `all` iterations. You need `all`.

Besides (more a mathematical issue), no need to loop to `x`, just use square root (inclusive) to reduce complexity.

My proposal:

```
print(max(filter(lambda x: all(x%i != 0 for i in range(2,int(x**0.5)+1)), a)))
```

Comment: I'm really greatful for your answer, thank you so much. It really worked. But still I didn't get the square root part. I mean, why would I need that? Excuse my noobness :) It would be really satisfactory me if you answered this question...

Comment: Let us say that you want to test for 47. Past 7, you would have found the divisors.no need to go further